# Win10 IoT + RPI3 WiFiAdapter throws Access Denied

Tags: c#, uwp, wifi, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

Trying to use the WiFi Adapter on a Raspberry Pi 3, using Windows 10 IoT

Code I'm trying to run:

```
 private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> ScanNetworksAsync()
    {
        var access = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();

        if (access != WiFiAccessStatus.Allowed)
        {
            throw new Exception("Not Allowed to use WiFi");
        }

        var wifi = WiFiAdapter.FindAllAdaptersAsync().AsTask().Result[0];

        await wifi.ScanAsync();

        return wifi.NetworkReport.AvailableNetworks.Select(n => n.Ssid);
    }
```

I do have the capability defined in the Package.appxmanifest:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="wiFiControl" />
```

When it tries to execute `wifi.ScanAsync()`, it just throws this error:

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of your WiFi Adapter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  It's something unclear or just missing from the documentation.

All the wifi commands such as `ScanAsync()` `ConnectAsync()` can not be run in the UI thread.
I was running them in a separate thread, but I was still blocking the UI anyway (didn't care cause it's just a test app).  Apparently that's not allowed.

I found a comment in the sample app:

```
        // RequestAccessAsync must have been called at least once by the app before using the API
        // Calling it multiple times is fine but not necessary
        // RequestAccessAsync must be called from the UI thread
```

Which implies `RequestAccessAsync()` only works if run in the UI thread.  I tested it both ways, and it seems to work no matter where it's run.

Comment: You figured it out, but what result did it yield, did it work? I'm getting the access denied error on `wifi.ScanAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was a missing capability in the `.appmanifest` file:

```
<Capabilities>
    <DeviceCapability Name="wiFiControl"/>
</Capabilities>
```